# Codifferential and Hodge star

Tags: differential-geometry

Is this true,
\begin{align}
\notag
\delta (f * \Omega )= f \delta (*\Omega)?
\end{align}
$\delta$ denotes codifferential, f is a function, $\Omega$ is a k-form and * is a Hodge star operator.

Comment: No, the left-hand side is given by a Leibniz-like rule (in particular, there should be a term on the r.h.s. that involves a derivative of $f$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\delta = \star d\star.$$

$\delta (f\star \Omega) = \star d \star (f\star \Omega) = \star  (-1)^ld(f\Omega) = .... $ clearly different. Here $l$ depends on the degree of $\Omega$...